# How to create Hashvalue for the data file based on sha256 algorithm in AIX

Tags: hash, aix, sha256

The following command works for SHA1: `csum -h SHA1 (FileName).txt > (FileName_chksum).txt`. How to create a similar file using the SHA256 algorithm in AIX?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `openssl` command from the `openssl.base` package; it has a `dgst` sub-command that will generate a SHA256 hash of the file:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 filename.txt > filename_sha256.txt
```

By default, it will print in the following format:

```
SHA256(filename.txt)= hash-string-here
```

The `csum` command prints in a slightly different format:

```
hash-string-here filename.txt
```

... so you may want to rearrange the output of `openssl` based on your specific needs for the filename_sha256.txt file.

If you only want the hashed string itself in the new file, you could use `awk`:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 filename.txt | awk '{print $2}' > filename_sha256.txt
```